# Searching for a key that doesn't and has never existed O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable

Let's take linear probing as an example because it's simple.

You have a (fictional) hash table who's keys look like this:

```
 1  2  3   4  5  6  7
[23|  | 44|67|89|  |22]
```

You want to check for the key 99, which doesn't exist. It gives the hash value 5.

Surely the algorithm goes like this:

```
Check 5: X
Check 6: X
Check 7: X
Check 1: X
Check 2: X
Check 3: X
Check 4: X
Reached 5 again: Key not found
```

Surely there is no way that the algorithm can tell if the key is present or not unless it checks the whole table.

However while searching for an answer for this, I stumbled upon this page:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx which states that it is O(1). Of course, if the key exists it can be O(1), but it won't be on average will it? And the worst case scenario (which is every time the key is not present?) would be O(n).

Am I correct in thinking this?

EDIT:
I just realised that it would stop when it hit an empty space... So this means that it would only reach O(n) if the table is full? Which must be why you don't want clustering?

Comment: Yes its possible to have a O(n) complexity for a key lookup operation but this case is very rare. This will only happen if your hash function is poor, i.e., all or almost all keys are mapped to the same bucket. If you have a good hash function determining the existence of a key is O(1).

Comment: The documentation does not state which collision resolution strategy is used. So you can't tell if it uses linear probing.

Comment: That's not the way the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented in .NET. Take a look at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just realised that it would stop when it hit an empty space... So
>   this means that it would only reach O(n) if the table is full? Which
>   must be why you don't want clustering?

You are right. Bear in mind that every decent hash table implementation that uses open addressing as a collision resolution technique (linear probing belongs to open addressing) stores a special number called load factor. Load factor is a ratio between the number of items in the hash table and the total number of available slots. When load factor increases over the certain value, hash table gets expanded - that is the way to keep number of probes small enough and to ensure good performance.

Since you searched for C# implementation, I took the time and found a [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms379571.aspx) describing hash table implementation in C# 2.0. It states:

> As aforementioned, Microsoft has tuned the Hashtable to use a default
>   load factor of 0.72. Therefore, for you can expect on average 3.5
>   probes per collision. Because this estimate does not vary based on the
>   number of items in the Hashtable, the asymptotic access time for a
>   Hashtable is O(1), which beats the pants off of the O(n) search time
>   for an array.